# How to write a wrapper for find?

Tags: bash, find

I'm doing text processing on a set of files, and it implies running find on them, and ignoring (and pruning) some directories, such as

```
find . -name '*.php' -not \( -path ./.git -prune -o -path ./.idea -prune \) -exec sed -E -i 's/function_call/refactored_function/g' {} '+'
```

The thing is the first part of the command (switches like `-name`, `-iname`, `-type` and what not) (before the `-not`) and the exec can change, and `find` is quite strict in its parameters. So How can I write a wrapper to find that will allow me to write :

```
otherfind . -name '*.php' -exec sed -E -i 's/function_call/refactored_function/g' {} '+'
```

And that will properly `-not \( -path ./.git -prune -o -path ./.idea -prune \)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of remembering how to get `find` to ignore files you don’t care about, or wrapping it, I would use `git grep`:

```
git grep -z -l function_call -- \*.php |
xargs -0 sed -E -i 's/function_call/refactored_function/g'
```

This will look for `function_call` in all files with a `.php` extension, ignoring ignored files (as defined in `.gitignore`) and the `.git` directory, and pass them to `xargs` for processing. The `-z` and `-0` options use null characters to separate file names.

Comment: Will git-grep ignore what is in .gitignore files ?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant by “ignoring ignored files” (I’ll make that clearer).